# Excel Power Query the best way to combine Excel Files with multiple Tables/Worksheets where WorkSheet may not exist in all Workbooks

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am using Excel Power Query to consolidate a number (300+) of Excel files from sharepoint document library

Each of the files will have one or more Tables/Worksheet. For example.

File 1: table1, table2, table3
File 2: table1, table2
File 3: table1, table3

I would like to combine table3 only across all the workbooks and ignore all other tables. How best can I acheive this?

When attempting to combined I receive an error stating key was not found

I found the below post but the m code doesn't seem to work in my file
[Excel Power Query - What's the best way to combine Excel Files with multiple Worksheets where WorkSheet may not exist in all Workbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59525718/excel-power-query-whats-the-best-way-to-combine-excel-files-with-multiple-wor)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This combines only Table3 from every workbook in a directory

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\directoryname\subdirectoryname\"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".xlsx")),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Name", "Content"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "GetFileData", each Excel.Workbook([Content],true)),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn( #"Added Custom", "GetFileData2", each Table.SelectRows([GetFileData], each [Name]="Table3")),
#"Expanded GetFileData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom1", "GetFileData2", {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Name"}, {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Sheet"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded GetFileData",{"Content", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind","GetFileData"}),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Removed Columns"[Data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Data", List,List)
in  #"Expanded Data"
```

If this doesn't work, please explain the error you are seeing

Comment: Hello, Thanks for this. So I received an error with the list step, see below. I deleted the step and filtered the sheet column and this seemed to work, not sure if this is the right thing to do but seems to have worked!                                                                                        error: we cannot convert the value null to type table